# Local index in Range interval partitioned table is not being used

Tags: oracle, range, query-optimization, partition

I have a range interval partitioned table. It has 6 trillion data for 1 year.

```
    CREATE TABLE eip.Meter_Read_Alert_test
     (
       Mfg_serial_num  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) ,
       Channel_id  NUMBER NOT NULL,
       Read_time TIMESTAMP(0),
       CONSTRAINT pk_Alert_test PRIMARY KEY (ID,channel_id,Read_time)
     )
     PARTITION BY RANGE (Read_time) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
     (  
       PARTITION p1 VALUES less than('01-09-19 12:00:00.000000000 AM')
     ) ;
```

Local index created on below columns:

```
CREATE INDEX mfg_SNo_test_idx on eip.Meter_Read_Alert_test ( Mfg_serial_num ) tablespace SPRING_METER_READ Local ;
CREATE INDEX channel_ID_test_idx on eip.Meter_Read_Alert_test (Channel_ID) tablespace SPRING_METER_READ   Local ;
CREATE INDEX ReadTime_test_idx on eip.Meter_Read_Alert_test (Read_Time) tablespace SPRING_METER_READ   Local ;
```

Issue:
When i run below query, ReadTime_test_idx index is not getting used. Full table scan is happening.

```
select * from meter_read_alert_test 
where  read_time between '19-11-2019 12:00:00 AM' and '19-11-2019 11:00:00 PM';

    Plan hash value: 2722527583

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                      |  9090K|   728M|   411K  (6)| 00:00:17 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                      |  9090K|   728M|   411K  (6)| 00:00:17 |   KEY |   KEY |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL      | METER_READ_ALERT_TEST |  9090K|   728M|   411K  (6)| 00:00:17 |   KEY |   KEY |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("READ_TIME">=TO_TIMESTAMP('19-11-2019 12:00:00 AM') AND 
              "READ_TIME"<=TO_TIMESTAMP('19-11-2019 11:00:00 PM'))
```

Please suggest what is wrong here and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is not necessarily doing anything wrong here by using a full table scan instead of an index range scan.  Full table scans are best when reading a large percentage of data, because full table scans can use a multi-block read and don't have to traverse a tree structure for every value, and if the index data is unordered an index read may have to retrieve all of the blocks from the table anyway.

While your query is only reading a small fraction of the overall data, it is reading a "large" percentage of data from the partition.  Since the table is month partitioned, Oracle is using partition pruning to instantly eliminate the majority of data (you can see that in action with the "Key" start and stop partitions).  Inside that partition, the query is reading about one day's worth of data, which is about 3% of the data in a partition.  There's not a generic number that represents what a "large" percentage is, but there are many cases where 3% is better read with a full table scan than an index.

There's a possibility that Oracle is making a wrong guess here.  You might want to try the query with an index hint like `select /*+ index(meter_read_alert_test) */ ...`.  If that improves the performance, first try regathering stats.  You shouldn't normally need to use index hints.